# Tensorflow Make tensor proto function getting error

Tags: python, tensorflow

make_tensor_proto function getting error Too many elements provided .needed at most 1, but received 541001, when passing that function a np.uint8 type value in it

Comment: Can you provide more details? What exactly does your code look like? Are you sure that your input is one of "a python scalar, a python list, a numpy ndarray, or a numpy scalar"?

Comment: Here are the details posted https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/issues/866